# Does apache short circuit mod rewrite conditions

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Here is my question

My simple regex is working just fine, i just want to make sure that the first part of the regex short circuits for efficiency, i put my questions inline

1- What this thing is supposed to do is, the files with the listed extensions should not be re-written if the file exists, if the file does not exist, we rewrite the request to our php file, all other file types are always rewritten, regardless of a file's existence.

---

- First condition, does the file have any of the following extensions?

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(php|gif|jpg|png|ico|swf|flv|avi|mpg|jpeg|gz|ram)$
```

- Second condition, if the file is one of our extensions above, does it exist on the file system?
- The evaluation of this statement is costly and I want to make sure that we short circuited  on the previous RewriteCond and that this will only be checked for value if the above evaluates to true.
- also need to know if the operating system or apache will cache the result of the file's existence (for example php does cache is_file() results)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my_index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- Directories and files to be left alone.... since if they passed
- the file existence test, they should not be rewritten at all

For example:

```
RewriteRule \.(php|gif|jpg|png|ico|swf|flv|avi|mpg|jpeg|gz|ram)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my_index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Answer (score 3):

No, it will parse each of your rewrite rules, of each type, in turn.  The regex may short-circuit or not depending on the libpcre, but each `RewriteRule`'s output is fed into the next rule in the list.  From the docs:

> Rewrite rules are applied to the results of previous rewrite rules,
>   in the order in which they are defined in the config file.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

However, one or more `RewriteCond` rules can exist before a `RewriteRule`, and these actually will short-circuit.  So, if the statements appear in the file in the order you have them:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(php|gif|jpg|png|ico|swf|flv|avi|mpg|jpeg|gz|ram)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my_index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

1. The extension will be checked; if it is not in that list the next `RewriteRule` will not be executed and all the `RewriteCond`s before it (the expensive one in particular) will not be checked.
2. Otherwise, the expensive filesystem `RewriteCond` will be evaulated; if it is false, the same thing happens as above.
3. If true, the URL is rewritten.

Comment: So let us recap quick
1- the expensive condition that will cause seek time will not be evaluated unless necessary
2- Apache or Linux will cache the file existence result in memory ? i think you missed this one
3- It is more efficient to rewrite the whole thing replacing the extra rules with conditions like the rewrite rules i will post in a second response here

Comment: This is the new one
`    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(php|gif|jpg|png|ico|swf|flv|avi|mpg|jpeg|gz|ram)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ st_index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !\.(php|gif|jpg|png|ico|swf|flv|avi|mpg|jpeg|gz|ram)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^style.css$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^datastor(.*)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^robots.txt$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^servex(.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bc_index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]